# Javascript Filter or Reduce each JSON object by child array of tags which contains search word

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I need help regarding filtering below given Javascript Array of Objects by it's sub-child array property.

I have one react app in which I want to filter articles when user types string in search box, but my question is related to just filtering objectby it's child array value.

## // My JSON Object

```
this.state = {
 articles: [
    {title: 'title 1', tags :["JavaScript", "ES6"], category: "JavaScript"},
    {title: 'title 2', tags :["React", "TypeScript"], category: "React"},
    {title: 'title 3', tags :["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"], category: "JavaScript"}
 ]
};
```

## // Output needed

```
// If user start typing in searchbox like "jav" then it should filter only those items which tags name matching with "jav". Tags is an Array

 [
    {title: 'title 1', tags :["JavaScript", "ES6"], category: "JavaScript"},
    {title: 'title 3', tags :["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"], category: "JavaScript"}
 ]
```

I had tried below given code but not giving proper result:

```
this.state.articles.reduce((newArticles: any, article: any) => {
            // let test1 = [];
            if (article.tags) {
                article.tags.map(tag => {
                    if (tag && tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value) === -1) {
                        newArticles.push(article);
                        // return article;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // newArticles.push(article);
            }

            console.log('test1 =', newArticles);
            return newArticles;
        }, []);
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear or need more information on it.

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `filter` method in inside check if `some` tag `includes` part of string that you want to search for.

```js
let articles = [{title: 'title 1', tags :["JavaScript", "ES6"], category: "JavaScript"},{title: 'title 2', tags :["React", "TypeScript"], category: "React"},{title: 'title 3', tags :["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"], category: "JavaScript"}]
 
let search = 'java';
let result = articles.filter(({tags}) => {
  return tags.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `filter` method in inside check if some tag includes part of the string that you want to search for.

```
let articles = [{title: 'title 1', tags :["JavaScript", "ES6"], category: "JavaScript"},{title: 'title 2', tags :["React", "TypeScript"], category: "React"},{title: 'title 3', tags :["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"], category: "JavaScript"}]

let search = "ES";
let result = articles.filter(((data)=>data.tags.some(v => v.includes(search))))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution. The fact you had unnescessary elements, is that you only checked if the property `children` had a value and was not `undefined`. with the check `node.children.length > 0` you check if the array has at least 1 item.

```js
    // the filter

const nodes = $.grep(data, function f(node) {
    const nodeIncludesValue = node.name.toLowerCase().includes(value);

    if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
        return $.grep(node.children, f) || nodeIncludesValue;
    }   

    return nodeIncludesValue;
});



// No unnecessary elements

createTree(nodes, container)
{
    const list = document.createElement('ul');

    nodes.forEach((node) => {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.textContent = node.name;
        list.appendChild(listItem);

        if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
            const childList = document.createElement('li');
            this.createTree(node.children, childList);
            list.appendChild(childList);
        }
    });

    container.appendChild(list);
}
```

Hopefully this helps you :)