# How to filter an array of object by multiple property values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If my array contains a value which is an array (multiple tags) how can I filter the array so it has to contain both tags. Working from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779336/javascript-filter-or-reduce-each-json-object-by-child-array-of-tags-which-contai) this is the code I have so far.

```
let articles = [{title: 'title 1', tags :["JavaScript", "ES6"], category: "JavaScript"},{title: 'title 2', tags :["React", "TypeScript"], category: "React"},{title: 'title 3', tags :["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"], category: "JavaScript"}]

let search = "ES6";
let search2 = "JavaScript";

let result = articles.filter(((data)=>data.tags.includes(search && search2)))

console.log(result)
```

But it seems to only filter as "either" rather than "both". In this example I would like it to return title 1 only.

Thanks

Comment: `data.tags.includes(search && search2)` will only check for `search2`, it's not even doing "either".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let articles = [{
  title: 'title 1',
  tags: ["JavaScript", "ES6"],
  category: "JavaScript"
}, {
  title: 'title 2',
  tags: ["React", "TypeScript"],
  category: "React"
}, {
  title: 'title 3',
  tags: ["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"],
  category: "JavaScript"
}]

let search = "ES6";
let search2 = "JavaScript";

let result = articles.filter(((data) => [search, search2].every((tag) => data.tags.includes(tag))))

console.log(result)
```

Alternative with cleaner syntax

```js
let articles = [{
  title: 'title 1',
  tags: ["JavaScript", "ES6"],
  category: "JavaScript"
}, {
  title: 'title 2',
  tags: ["React", "TypeScript"],
  category: "React"
}, {
  title: 'title 3',
  tags: ["JavaScript", "Inheritance", "Prototype"],
  category: "JavaScript"
}]

let search = "ES6";
let search2 = "JavaScript";

let result = articles.filter(((data) => data.tags.includes(search) && data.tags.includes(search2)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for the wanted strings and check against all with a short circuit.

```
result = articles.filter(({ tags }) => [search, search2].some(s => tags.includes(s)));
```

Comment: instead of some, every must be used.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the set to get the search done on unique array elements in each tags:

```
let search = "ES6";
let search2 = "JavaScript";
let articles = [{tags:["ES6", "JavaScript"]}, {tags:["ES6", "JavaQScript"]}, {tags:[ "JavaScript"]}, {tags:["ES6"]}]

let result = articles.filter((data)=>{const set1 = new Set(data.tags); return (set1.has(search) && set1.has(search2)) })

console.log(result)
```