# Best way to filter an array by multiple properties?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter an array and remove the entries that contain certain properties. For example, my array looks like this:

```
const items = [{a: "apple", b: "banana", c: "coconut"}, {a: "apple"}, {b: "banana, c: "coconut"}];
```

And I want to filter out the items that have the properties b or c.

Right now I have:

```
items.filter(item => "b" in item || "c" in item);
```

but I feel like there is a better way to do this, and set it up so a lot more properties could easily be added in the future.

Comment: Your code is keeping the items with b or c, not filtering them out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array based on property value, or existence of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207150/how-to-filter-an-array-based-on-property-value-or-existence-of-properties)

Comment: @pilchard That doesn't show how to do multiple properties, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @Barmar then combine it with [How to filter an array of object by multiple property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576333/how-to-filter-an-array-of-object-by-multiple-property-values)

Comment: @pilchard That question asks how to change "either" to "all". But this question asks how to do "either". It's also not filtering by property values, just by property existence.

Answer (score 1):

Put the property names in an array, and use `.some()` to test if any of those properties exists.

```js
const items = [{
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "coconut"
}, {
  a: "apple"
}, {
  b: "banana",
  c: "coconut"
}];

let properties_to_filter = ["b", "c"]
let result = items.filter(item => properties_to_filter.some(prop => prop in item));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: better to use `Object.hasOwn` over `in` unless you explicitly want to test the entire prototype chain

Answer (score 0):

```js
      const items = [{a: "apple", b: "banana", c: "coconut"}, {a: "apple"}, {b: "banana", c: "coconut"}]

      let filtredKey = ["a"]

      let result = []
      items.map(el => {
        if(el.hasOwnProperty("c"))
          result.push(el)
      })

      console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is `filtredKey` doing?

Comment: The question is about how to do it for multiple properties.