# Javascript to filter JSON object if child array contains item

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to filter a JSON object `orig` which looks like the following.

```
orig = [
        {model: 'model1', fields :{target:[1, 2], another_field:"random1"}},
        {model: 'model2', fields :{target:[1, 3, 4], another_field:"random2"}},
        {model: 'model3', fields :{target:[2, 5], another_field:"random3"}}
     ]
```

I want to be able to use the filter `target_filter = 1` to retrieve every item in `orig` whose target array contains 1. So the expected output is:

```
filtered = [        
        {model: 'model1', fields :{target:[1, 2], another_field:"random1"}},
        {model: 'model2', fields :{target:[1, 3, 4], another_field:"random2"}},
]
```

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779336/javascript-filter-or-reduce-each-json-object-by-child-array-of-tags-which-contai) but I am not sure how to make it work if the child array is deeper. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: const filtered  = orig.filter(obj => obj.fields.target.includes(1));

Comment: Thanks @RezaM. for the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could address the right property and check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array = [{ model: 'model1', fields: { target: [1, 2], another_field: "random1" } }, { model: 'model2', fields: { target: [1, 3, 4], another_field: "random2" } }, { model: 'model3', fields: { target: [2, 5], another_field: "random3" } }],
    target_filter = 1,
    result = array.filter(({ fields: { target } }) => target.includes(target_filter));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you might use

```
array.filter(object => object.fields.target.includes(target_filter))
```

Comment: This would probably be easier to understand without the destructoring.